# Fill up four slots of parallel processes constantly even when some finish

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, process

I have a script that runs batches of 4 processes at a time, I don't care about getting the return codes of each proc. I don't ever want to run more than 4 procs concurrently. The issue with below approach is that it does not fill up to 4 procs at a time. For example, if proc2 and proc3 finished early, i would like proc 5 and 6 to start, rather than only starting once 1-4 are complete. How can I achieve this in bash?

```
run_func_1 &
run_func_2 &
run_func_3 &
run_func_4 &
wait
run_func_5 &
run_func_6 &
run_func_7 &
run_func_8 &
wait
```

Comment: Try to think outside of bash. You'll probably need a queue of jobs (func1, func2, func3..). Then you add some loop which will get a job from the queue and run it in the background but never run more than 4 of them at a time.

Comment: Have a look at GNU `parallel`. Something like `parallel -j 4 <listoffunctions.txt` might be a good starter. I don't know the tool well enough to write a proper answer though. man page is [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html).

Comment: [Sister-site](http://unix.stackexchange.com) had a nice answer to a similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216475

Comment: `bash` is fine if you just want *at most* 4 jobs running at a time, but it doesn't have the facilities you need to easily *keep* 4 jobs running as much as possible.

Comment: GNU parallel not installed, locked down env :(

Comment: @tooptoop4 Can you elaborate on why you cannot use one of the options mentioned on https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216475/23692

Comment: @OleTange - corporate env, only central team has root access and they keep it locked

Comment: @tooptoop4 But as you can see from https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/ root access has never been a requirement for neither a personal installation nor `parallel --embed`. So can you elaborate on why you do not use those options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do a custom implementation with pool of workers and queue of jobs.
New worker will take job from the queue as soon as it finishes with previous one.

You can probably adapt this script to whatever you need, but I hope you will see my intentions.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

f1() { echo Started f1; sleep 10; echo Finished f1; }
f2() { echo Started f2; sleep 8; echo Finished f2; }
f3() { echo Started f3; sleep 12; echo Finished f3; }
f4() { echo Started f4; sleep 14; echo Finished f4; }
f5() { echo Started f5; sleep 7; echo Finished f5; }

declare -r MAX_WORKERS=2
declare -a worker_pids
declare -a jobs=('f1' 'f2' 'f3' 'f4' 'f5')

available_worker_index() {
    # If number of workers is less than MAX_WORKERS
    # We still have workers that are idle
    declare worker_count="${#worker_pids[@]}"
    if [[ $worker_count -lt $MAX_WORKERS ]]; then
        echo "$worker_count"
        return 0
    fi

    # If we reached this code it means
    # All workers are already created and executing a job
    # We should check which of them finished and return it's index as available
    declare -i index=0
    for pid in "${worker_pids[@]}"; do
        is_running=$(ps -p "$pid" > /dev/null; echo "$?")
        if [[ $is_running != 0 ]]; then
            echo "$index"
            return 0
        fi
        index+=1
    done

    echo "None"
}

for job in "${jobs[@]}"; do
    declare worker_index
    worker_index=$(available_worker_index)
    while [[ $worker_index == "None" ]]; do
        # Wait for available worker
        sleep 3
        worker_index=$(available_worker_index)
    done

    # Run the job in background
    "$job" &

    # Save it's pid for later
    pid="$!"
    worker_pids["$worker_index"]="$pid"
done

# Wait all workers to finish
wait
```

You can easily change size of the worker pool only by changing `MAX_WORKERS` variable.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU Parallel it is as simple as:

```
parallel -j4 ::: run_func_{1..8}
```

Just remember to `export -f` the functions.

If GNU Parallel is not installed, use

```
parallel --embed > new_script
```

to generate a shell script which embeds GNU Parallel. You then simple change the end of `new_script`.

By default it will run one job per cpu-core. This can be adjusted with `--jobs`.

GNU Parallel is a general parallelizer and makes is easy to run jobs in parallel on the same machine or on multiple machines you have ssh access to.

If you have 32 different jobs you want to run on 4 CPUs, a straight forward way to parallelize is to run 8 jobs on each CPU:

[image: Simple scheduling]

GNU Parallel instead spawns a new process when one finishes - keeping the CPUs active and thus saving time:

[image: GNU Parallel scheduling]

**Installation**

For security reasons you should install GNU Parallel with your package manager, but if GNU Parallel is not packaged for your distribution, you can do a personal installation, which does not require root access. It can be done in 10 seconds by doing this:

```
$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || lynx -source pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || \
   fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3 ) > install.sh
$ sha1sum install.sh | grep 883c667e01eed62f975ad28b6d50e22a
12345678 883c667e 01eed62f 975ad28b 6d50e22a
$ md5sum install.sh | grep cc21b4c943fd03e93ae1ae49e28573c0
cc21b4c9 43fd03e9 3ae1ae49 e28573c0
$ sha512sum install.sh | grep da012ec113b49a54e705f86d51e784ebced224fdf
79945d9d 250b42a4 2067bb00 99da012e c113b49a 54e705f8 6d51e784 ebced224
fdff3f52 ca588d64 e75f6033 61bd543f d631f592 2f87ceb2 ab034149 6df84a35
$ bash install.sh
```

For other installation options see http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/README

**Learn more**

See more examples: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html

Watch the intro videos: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Sign up for the email list to get support: https://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/parallel

Comment: bash-4.1$ (wget -O - pi.dk/3 || curl pi.dk/3/ || fetch -o - http://pi.dk/3) | bash
--2018-05-09 10:54:55--  http://pi.dk/3
Resolving pi.dk... 188.138.2.24
Connecting to pi.dk|188.138.2.24|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 503 Service Unavailable
2018-05-09 10:54:57 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
101  3655  101  3655    0     0  11555      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 3569k
bash: line 1: html: No suchf

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. Do you get the same error if you test on another system?